# MS Charts C# DataSource from array or List

Tags: c#, list, arrays, datasource, charts

i want to fill the data of the charts from values i have in 2D array, one column will present the X-axis and the second is present the Y-axis.. i did it, but its not reading from the array, it gives me the default line when i run the application, i found a solution using List<>, i had an error, so if any one could help me in this, i will be thankful :D

this is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ICS381Project
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[,] AndFunction = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 } }; // intialized the function
            int[,] D_n = new int[4, 1]; // creating the D(n)
            int[,] x_n = new int[4, 3]; // creating X(n) vectors X1 --> x4
            int[,] W_n = { { 0, 0, 0 } }; // creating and intiallizing W(n) vectors W1 --> w4
            int[,] W_n_1 = { { 0, 0, 0 } };
            int[,] Delta_W_n = { { 0, 0, 0 } };
            int wx = 0; // 
            int Y_n = 0; //
            int d_y = 0; // 
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                D_n[i, 0] = AndFunction[i, 2];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (j == 2)
                        x_n[i, j] = 1;
                    else
                        x_n[i, j] = AndFunction[i, j];
                }
            }
            int step = 0;
            int CheckIfNoLearning = 0;
            int RowsPointer = 0;
            while (CheckIfNoLearning < 4)
            {

                //Console.Write("step= " + step+1 + "\n");
                wx = (x_n[RowsPointer, 0] * W_n[0, 0]) + (x_n[RowsPointer, 1] * W_n[0, 1]) + (x_n[RowsPointer, 2] * W_n[0, 2]);
                //Console.Write("[ " + x_n[RowsPointer, 0] + ", " + x_n[RowsPointer, 1] + ", " + x_n[RowsPointer, 2] + "] \t");
                //Console.Write("[ " + W_n[0, 0] + ", " + W_n[0, 1] + ", " + W_n[0, 2] + "] \t");
                //Console.Write("" + wx + "\t");
                if (wx < 0)
                    Y_n = 0;
                else
                    Y_n = 1;
               // Console.Write("" + Y_n + "\t");
                d_y = D_n[RowsPointer, 0] - Y_n;
               // Console.Write("" + d_y + "\t");
                Delta_W_n[0, 0] = d_y * x_n[RowsPointer, 0];
                Delta_W_n[0, 1] = d_y * x_n[RowsPointer, 1];
                Delta_W_n[0, 2] = d_y * x_n[RowsPointer, 2];
               // Console.Write("[ " + Delta_W_n[0, 0] + ", " + Delta_W_n[0, 1] + ", " + Delta_W_n[0, 2] + "] \t");
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    W_n_1[0, i] = W_n[0, i] + Delta_W_n[0, i];
                }
                //Console.Write("[ " + W_n_1[0, 0] + ", " + W_n_1[0, 1] + ", " + W_n_1[0, 2] + "] \n");

                if (W_n_1[0, 0] == W_n[0, 0] && W_n_1[0, 1] == W_n[0, 1] && W_n_1[0, 2] == W_n[0, 2] && CheckIfNoLearning == RowsPointer)
                    CheckIfNoLearning++;
                else
                    CheckIfNoLearning = 0;
                W_n[0, 0] = W_n_1[0, 0];
                W_n[0, 1] = W_n_1[0, 1];
                W_n[0, 2] = W_n_1[0, 2];
                //Console.Write("W_n= [ " + W_n[0, 0] + ", " + W_n[0, 1] + ", " + W_n[0, 2] + "] \n");
                RowsPointer = (RowsPointer + 1) % 4;
                step++;
            }

            double[,] equation = {{-10,0},{-9,0},{-8,0},
                              {-7,0},{-6,0},{-5,0},
                              {-4,0},{-3,0},{-2,0},
                              {-1,0},{0,0},{1,0},
                              {2,0},{3,0},{4,0},
                              {5,0},{6,0},{7,0},
                              {8,0},{9,0},{10,0}};
            List<XY> xy = new List<XY>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            {
                equation[i, 1] = (-1 * (W_n_1[0, 1] * equation[i, 0] + W_n_1[0, 2])) / W_n_1[0, 0];
                xy.Add(new XY(equation[i,0], equation[i,1]));
            }

            chart1.DataSource = xy;
            chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Y";
            chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "X";
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart1.DataBind();





        }
    }
    public class XY
    {
        private double X;
        private double Y;

        public double DayOfWeek
        {
            get { return X; }
            set { X = value; }
        }

        public double Sales
        {
            get { return Y; }
            set { Y = value; }
        }
        public XY(double X, double Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this error on the Chart1.dataBinding();     ___  ___ 

Series data points do not support values of type ICS381Project.XY only values of these types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XY class, instead of the private fields:

```
  private double X;
  private double Y;
```

use public properties:

```
 public double X { get; private set; }
 public double Y { get; private set; }
```

DataBinding does not work on fields.

Comment: yeah that solved the problem plus i had some error in the properties names :D


thanks :D

Comment: Henk, Great answer. This is the only place on the Internets with an answer to the problem. Many Thanks.