# How to bind Dapper.NET with MS Charts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dapper

I need to bind Dapper.NET dynamic query with MS Charts.

So the question is , how do i get it done?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly ChartModel _model; 

    public HomeController(ChartModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }



    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewModel.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
    }



    public ChartResult GetChart()
    {
        var data = _model.GetChartData();

        var chart = new Chart(400, 200, ChartTheme.Blue)
                    .AddTitle("Price enquiries")
                    .DataBindTable(???, "XXX");
        return new ChartResult(chart, "png");
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }        
}
```

this is the code i use.

Comment: " so please be bare with me " - that sound rather.... intimate?

Comment: thanks i will try next time to sound romantic also :) lol

Answer (score 2):

Dapper can be used to conveniently populate an object model, such as a list - i.e.

```
var list = connection.Query<SomeType>(sql, args).ToList();
```

I guess the real question, then, is not "how to bind dapper to a chart", but rather, "how to bind a typed list to a chart"; for that - look at questions like this: [MS Charts C# DataSource from array or List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940120/ms-charts-c-sharp-datasource-from-array-or-list)

Comment: If i don't want to bind to a concrete type, I want totally dynamic?

Comment: @IamStalker - k; dapper can handle that (the non-generic version of Query) - however, the real question here is "can MS chart?". I honestly don't know what MS chart can handle here. But: I doubt it will handle `dynamic` - at best I would expect it to handle `ITypedList`, but that requires writing custom property descriptors. Are you familiar with the `TypeDescriptor` model?